# glPopAttrib & GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

I'm working on some graphical application and i got an `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` after `glPopAttrib()`. Predicting the answer "It seems you call `glPopAttrib()` within `glBegin/glEnd` block" please see this log i've made with GLIntercept.

```
/* tons of wglGetProcAddress* */
wglGetProcAddress("glEndOcclusionQueryNV")=087C9B10 
wglGetProcAddress("glBeginTransformFeedbackN...")=087C9ED0 
wglGetProcAddress("glEndTransformFeedbackNV")=087C9F00 
glPushAttrib(GL_VIEWPORT_BIT)
glPushAttrib(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
glPushAttrib(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
glPopAttrib()
glPopAttrib() glGetError() = GL_INVALID_OPERATION # <---- THIS
glPopAttrib()
glPushAttrib(GL_VIEWPORT_BIT)
glPushAttrib(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
glPushAttrib(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
glPopAttrib()
glPushAttrib(GL_POINT_BIT | GL_LINE_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
glPopAttrib()
glPopAttrib()
glPopAttrib()
glPushAttrib(GL_VIEWPORT_BIT)
glPushAttrib(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
glPushAttrib(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
glPopAttrib()
glPopAttrib()
glPopAttrib()
/* and so on */
```

No `glBegin/glEnd` callings are made before error-causeing `glPopAttrib()`. (I used findstr commad to filter the log).

The error appears only once, no such (or others) error appers again during the code execution. I have an suspicion that i should call some function before `glPushAttrib(GL_VIEWPORT_BIT)` or something.

Comment: That means that the error occured before a call to glPopAttrib

Comment: No it doesn't. GLIntercept returns the errors that happened for the specific command on which they actually happened.

Comment: You mean to say that after first fail all the following rendering loops are okay? So that error happens only once on first pass?

Comment: @Krom: exactly, it works fine besides this strange error

Comment: I have the same problem right now, any results?

Comment: What are you running this on?

Comment: Just as an experiment, it might be interesting to do a flush before, if possible

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem, and finally figured out the cause:
When you call a `glBindFramebuffer` between a `glPushAttrib(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` and a `glPopAttrib`, a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` is caused on the glPopAttrib call.

This even happens when you restore the original frame buffer binding before calling glPopAttrib.

The only solution seems to be either avoid all glBindFramebuffer calls between the glPushAttrib and glPopAttrib, or avoid using glPushAttrib and glPopAttrib by storing and restoring all relevant color buffer state manually.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting problem. Got me thinking ..

What could be happening is that some of the state variables associated with the `COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` were not initialized with proper values when the OpenGL context was got from the window system. When you did a `glPushAttrib`, those (probably) incorrect values were saved, and when the attrib was popped, the incorrect values were restored - causing a invalid operation ? Does that sound logical ?